# Загрузка классов, порядок инициализации

Tags: java, классы, загрузка, classloader

```
public class A{

    static int a = 1111;
    static
    {
            a = a-- - --a;
    }

    {
            a = a++ + ++a;
    }

     public static void main(String[] args)  {
           System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
```

Спрашивают, что выведет программа. Мне ясно, что если мы не создали экземпляра класса, то переменные уровня класса (статические) они будут проинициализированы, ну и статический блок тоже будет выполнен, даже если экземпляр класса не создан. И ответ тут 2. Потому, что на момент вызова выполнился только статический блок инициализации. Но у меня вопрос в другом. Я думал, что будет исключение NPE , так как переменная `а` еще не существует. А думал, я так потому что полагал что точка входа `public static void main(String[] args)` выполняется сперва, а потом уже по порядку инициализация проходит.

Так вот в какой момент успели проинициализироваться статическое поле и стат. блок класса `А`?

Comment: Какой NPE может быть на примитиве?

Comment: Сначала загружается весь класс целиком, включая всю статическую инициализацию, и только потом могут вызываться какие-либо методы

Comment: А когда этот примитив вообще успел создаться?   аа..кажется я понял. Сперва загружаются все классы и инициализируется всё статическоё в установленном порядке, т.е. сперва этот класс A , в нем стат. переменная, потом стат. блок , а потом стат.метод создается. Так ? А то я думал что точка входа это метод и значит он первый создается.

Comment: А что если есть два класса A и B и у каждого по две стат. переменной. Думаю они инициализироваться будут тупо по порядку. Сперва класс A потом B , как и расположены в папке.. А вот если первой переменной в классе А присваивается значение переменной из класса B , то порядок немного нарушается. Сперва класс A , дошли до первой переменной, попали в класс B, проинициализировали его поля полностью(или только то самое статическое поле? ) и потом вернулись и проинициализировали вторую переменную класса А.  Кажется это уже тонкости classLoader в которые пока лезть не стоит

Comment: @Turalllb Статические переменные класса инициализируются тогда, когда класс загружается. Загружается он тогда, когда к нему кто-нибудь обращается (создает экземпляр или обращается к статическому члену). К классу, который содержит метод `main` обращается виртуальная машина, когда мы запускаем программу, указав ей в качестве аргумента этот класс. Если класс никем не используется, то он и не инициализируется. Порядок расположения в директории не играет никакой роли.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Инициализация класса**

Перед инициализацией загрузка необходимых классов (ClassLoader, java.lang ... требует отдельного рассмотрения)

Порядок инициализации:

1. Первым инициализируется статический блок инициализации класса
2. Затем инициализируются блоки инициализации
3. Затем вызывается метод public static void main(String[] args), который является точкой входа в приложение. Он должен быть написан по стандарту.
4. И в самом конце вызывается конструктор класса

Пример кода:

```
 /**    
 Инициализация класса

Порядок  инициализации:
 
1. Первым инициализируется статический блок инициализации класса
2. Затем инициализируются блоки инициализации
3. Затем вызывается метод public static void main(String[] args), который является точкой входа в приложение и в самом конце вызывается конструктор класса

 *Примечание.* 
 

1.  Метод, имя которого совпадает с конструктором не вызывается при
    инициализации.  
2.  Метод, имя которого main() в моем коде, но который не является
    точкой входа, не вызывается при инициализации. Не является он точкой входа, потому как возвращает void и не имеет аргументов.
3.  Обычные статические методы не вызываются при инициализации.
4.  Обычные нестатические методы не вызываются при инициализации.    
     */
    public class InitClass {
        InitClass(){ // конструктор класса
        System.out.print(" Конструктор "); 
        }
        { // блок инициализации
         System.out.print(" 3 "); 
        } 
        void InitClass(){// имя метода совпадает с именем конструктора но возвращает void
        // метод не вызывается при инициализации
        System.out.print(" метод InitClass "); 
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) { 
        System.out.print(" 2 "); 
        new InitClass(); 
        } 
        public void main(){ //- это обычный метод с именем main
         // имя метода совпадает с именем точки входа, но не имеет аргументов
        // метод не вызывается при инициализации
        System.out.print(" метод main - не точка входа "); 
        }
        public static void method(){ // статический метод
        // метод не вызывается при инициализации
        System.out.print("статичные метод с именем  method()"); 
        }
        static { // статический блок инициализации
        System.out.print(" 1 "); 
        } 
    }
    /*
    run:
     1  2  3  Конструктор BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
    */
```

Comment: Код ясный, а вот написали всё очень сумбурно. С порядком инициализации я знаком, просто почему то методу `public static void main(String[] args)` придавал особое значение, думал он самый первый и инициализируется, раз является точкой входа. Выходит он инициализируется как обычный статический метод.

Comment: Метод public static void main(String[] args) действительно является точкой входа. Если вы напишите метод public void main(){} - то это будет обычный метод и он не вызовется при инициализации. Но до точки входа происходит вызов блоков инициализации.