# Место метода main() в порядке инициализации класса в Java

Tags: java, память, конструктор, инициализация

Я - новичок в Java. И сейчас меня очень занимает вопрос инициализации класса. Я наткнулся на такое объяснение с примером на странице https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/847576/396180:

Порядок  инициализации:

1. Первым инициализируется статический блок инициализации класса
2. Затем инициализируются блоки инициализации
3. Затем вызывается метод public static void main(String[] args), который является точкой входа в приложение и в самом конце вызывается конструктор класса

*Примечание.*

1. Метод, имя которого совпадает с конструктором не вызывается при
   инициализации.
2. Метод, имя которого main() в моем коде, но который не является
   точкой входа, не вызывается при инициализации. Не является он точкой входа, потому как возвращает void и не имеет аргументов.
3. Обычные статические методы не вызываются при инициализации.
4. Обычные нестатические методы не вызываются при инициализации.

Пример кода:

> ```
> public class InitClass {
>     InitClass(){ // конструктор класса
>     System.out.print(" Конструктор "); 
>     }
>     { // блок инициализации
>      System.out.print(" 3 "); 
>     } 
>     void InitClass(){// имя метода совпадает с именем конструктора но возвращает void
>     // метод не вызывается при инициализации
>     System.out.print(" метод InitClass "); 
>     }
>     public static void main(String[] args) { 
>     System.out.print(" 2 "); 
>     new InitClass(); 
>     } 
>     public void main(){ //- это обычный метод с именем main
>      // имя метода совпадает с именем точки входа, но не имеет аргументов
>     // метод не вызывается при инициализации
>     System.out.print(" метод main - не точка входа "); 
>     }
>     public static void method(){ // статический метод
>     // метод не вызывается при инициализации
>     System.out.print("статичные метод с именем  method()"); 
>     }
>     static { // статический блок инициализации
>     System.out.print(" 1 "); 
>     } 
> }
>
> /*
> run:
>  1  2  3  Конструктор BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
> */
> ```

Я не могу понять: почему, если метод

```
 public static void main(String[] args) { 
         System.out.print(" 2 "); 
         new InitClass();  }
```

вызывается **после** блока инициализации, мы видим " 2 " **раньше** " 3 " в блоке инициализации ? Спасибо!

Comment: Какой вопрос такой и ответ, так тут пишут ответы. Сам не могу понять. Там нуда читать коммент: "Если вы напишите метод public void main(){} - то это будет обычный метод и он не вызовется при инициализации. Но до точки входа происходит вызов блоков инициализации."

Comment: @Roman C "Но до точки входа происходит вызов блоков инициализации" . Да, именно об этом говорит и сам ответ, не только коммент.  1 мы получаем из статического блока, 2 - из main(), 3 - из нестатического блока. НО и отчего же тогда при выполнении я вижу 1 2 3 Конструктор вместо 1 3 2 Конструктор ?)

Comment: Наверно потому, что вы перепутали статическое с нестатическим, и поэтому у вас порядок изменился.

Comment: Потому что инициализация _экземпляра_ происходит после вызова конструктора этого класса в коде.  И соответственно выполняются: **1) блок статической инициализации**  **2) вызов статического метода `main`** и печать "2"  **3) выполнение блока инициализации экземпляра** **4) выполнение конструктора**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> НО и отчего же тогда при выполнении я вижу 1 2 3 Конструктор вместо 1 3 2 Конструктор ?)

то есть 2 вызывается раньше чем 3, потому что метод

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

статический. Статическое вызывается раньше чем нестатическое, поскольку обращение к классу происходит в статической памяти.

Более меннее адекватное понимание статической памяти можно почитать [здесь](https://tproger.ru/articles/memory-model/).

Comment: ДА! Но тогда получается, что приведенный порядок инициализации написан некорректно и main() должен идти после статического блока, но перед нестатическим, а не после блоков инициализации. В общем, я запутался, потом вроде распутался и снова запутался)

Comment: Я же вам писал в коменте, что статическое вызывается раньше чем нестатическое, потому что это происходит при загрузке класса из которого вызывается `main()`, ну а потом вы создаете *экземпляр*, поэтому вызывается блок инициализации перед конструктором.

Comment: Роман, спасибо за Ваше время и ссылку!