# Ошибка: Main method not found in class Main

Tags: java

Код выдает ошибку:

```
public class Main{
    public static String calc(){
        String latin = new String();
        latin = "I";
        System.out.println(latin);
        return latin;
    }
}
```

---

Error: Main method not found in class Main, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: А почему бы не сделать так, как написано в сообщении об ошибке?

Comment: Без метода main,  метод public static void main(String[] args), который является точкой входа в приложение, запустить программу нельзя, поэтому компилятор выдает ошибку. Надо добавить этот метод в класс. Чтобы понять что происходит при запуске программы и место метода main читай [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1449761/204920)

Answer (score -1):

Метода не было.
Исправленный код:

```
public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String ltn = calc();
            System.out.println(ltn);
        }

        public static String calc(){
            String latin = new String();
            latin = "I";
            System.out.println(latin);
            return latin;
        }

}
```

Comment: Привет, спасибо за решение, но есть ещё вопрос было бы здорово если ты смог бы ещё помочь.
У меня задача сделать калькулятор и в условиях прописано вот это:
             "Реализуй класс Main с методом public static String calc(String input). Метод должен принимать строку с арифметическим выражением между двумя числами и возвращать строку с результатом их выполнения. Ты можешь добавлять свои импорты, классы и методы. Добавленные классы не должны иметь модификаторы доступа (public или другие)"
То, что ты написал не будет противоречить требованиям?

Comment: Я вижу, что ты добавил второй метод, хотя ты написал, что его у меня не было, но разве String calc не метод?