# Почему статический метод не может вызвать не статический, но может вызывать конструктор?

Tags: методы, конструктор, инициализация

Алгоритм создания объекта потомка:

1. Инициализируются **статические** данные класса-предка, включая статические блоки инициализации;
2. Инициализируются **статические** данные класса-потомка, включая статические блоки инициализации;
3. Инициализируются **нестатические** данные класса-предка;
4. Инициализируются **конструкторы** класса-предка;
5. Инициализируются **нестатические** данные класса-потомка;
6. Вызывается **конструктор** класса-потомка;

Если все верно, то в момент инициализации статического метода конструктора не существует. Так почему же он в нарушение казалось бы принципа загрузки может к нему обращаться. При этом всем, статический метод логично не может вызвать не статический.

Comment: Что такое "инициализация статического метода"? Методы и конструкторы существуют всегда, и у них не бывает никакой инициализации

Comment: Вообще, если вбить фразу «инициализируются конструкторы» в гугл, то выводится всего 7 результатов, что намекает на то, что это какая-то чушь, вероятно, написанная кем-то случайно по невнимательности

Comment: Если комментатор знает как надо написать, буду рад поправиться. Может не "инициализация" в данном случае, а загрузка классов, полей, методов в JVM.

Comment: «загрузка классов, полей, методов» выполняется задолго до создания объекта, и к моменту создания объектов это всё уже давно существует и может быть спокойно вызвано, в том числе никто не запрещает вызывать конструкторы

Comment: Тогда и не статические методы тоже нет смысла запрещать вызывать из статических, а это запрещено компилятором

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/847511/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8 Здесь например обсуждается аналогичный вопрос и "инициализация" там никого не возмущает

Comment: Как вы собираетесь вызывать нестатический метод из статического? Что такое `this` в статическом методе?